# Intellij automatic directory addition to a war file

Tags: java, maven, web-services, intellij-idea

I'd like to add a WEB-INF/views directory to my *.war file generated using maven's goals. How do I do that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pu your `views` directory to the `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF` folder in your project and then build it using `maven-war-plugin` with default configuration like this

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
 </plugin>
```

you will get your `views` inside of `WEB-INF`

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot!